# Is it possible to change the font size of the header in the Material Datepicker component on Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, materialdatepicker

My team wants me to change the font size of the Material Datepicker title to be more visible for accessibility reasons on Android. Is it possible and how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change the size of Title.

Material Date Picker uses this theme

```
 <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- just override the colors used in the default style -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/spruce_valencia</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/date_text_appearance</item>

</style>

<style name="date_text_appearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_xlarge_heading</item>
</style>
```

**materialCalendarHeaderTitle** is what does the trick and rest you can change the use **textSize** attribute to change the Text Size.

[image: Here is how it looks]

More about Material Date Picker attributes and layouts you can trace back this
[google material repo.](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-alpha02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/res/layout/mtrl_picker_header_title_text.xml)

Here is the [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.6.0-alpha03.1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/res/values/styles.xml) to all the styles which are used in the Material Date Picker just find the relevant style applied in layouts and customise. Enjoy.